# Stochastic Optimal Control

Tags: stochastic-calculus, optimal-control

The general formulation of a stochastic control problem with finite horizon is

$$V(x)=\sup_{u\in\mathbb{U}}E\left(G(X_{T}^{u}) + \int_{0}^{T}F(s,X_{s}^{u}, u_{s})ds|X_{0}^{u}=c\right)$$

where $X_{s}^{u}$ is the solution of the SDE $dX_{t}^{u}=\mu(t,X_{t}^{u},u_{t})dt + \sigma(t,X_{t}^{u},u_{t})dW_{t}$

I am trying to understand an optimal control problem that wants to maximise the survival probability $\delta^{b}(x)=1-P(\tau^{b}<\infty|X_{0}^{b}=x)$ where $\tau^{b}=\inf \lbrace t\geq 0 : X_{t}^{b}<0\rbrace$. In this case the value function would be $\delta(x)=\sup_{b\in \mathbb{U}}\delta^{b}(x)$

How can I write $\delta(x)$ in terms of the general formulation? What are the values of $F$ and $G$?

Comment: Well, you cannot hope for this in general. In discrete time setting this formulation would be different.

Comment: @Ilya I saw in a book that in terms of the general formulation $F=0$ and $G=-1$, and they add $1$ to the value function, but that does not make sense to me.

Comment: What did you see there exactly?

Comment: @Ilya I think I understand it now, it says $F=0$, $G=-1$ and $T=\tau^{b}$. If $T=\tau^{b}$ the function $G$ needs to be multiplied by the indicator of $\tau^{b}<\infty$. That gives the correct value function

Comment: I've had an impression that $T$ must be a fixed time horizon here, not a random variable. It does not have to?

Comment: It can be a stopping time

Comment: well, then you are done, I guess